# powershell: How to create and access static variables in a powershell class?

Tags: powershell

How to create a powershell class that has static variables?

```
class ex1 {
    static [int]$count = 0

    ex1() {
        [ex1]::count = [ex1]::count + 1
        write-host [ex1]::count
    }
}

$ex1 = [ex1]::new()
$ex2 = [ex1]::new()
$ex3 = [ex1]::new()

exit 1
```

I tried this but all it does it prints:

```
[ex1]::new()
[ex1]::new()
[ex1]::new()
```

instead of incrementing the count to count the number of objects created in the static integer.

Comment: As an aside: `[ex1]::count = [ex1]::count + 1` can be simplified to `++[ex1]::count`

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution: Enclose static variable references like `[ex1]::count` in parentheses, whenever you want to pass them **as an argument to another command** like `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host ([ex1]::count)
```

Why is that necessary when simple variables like `$someVar` don't require parentheses? For the same reason that `Write-Host 2+2` doesn't print `4` but literally `2+2`: PowerShells often counterintuitive [argument parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1#argument-mode).

PowerShell switches from normal *expression parsing* mode to *argument parsing* mode, whenever it sees a call to a command (compare with a call to a .NET function, which doesn't change parsing mode). This mode follows [its own rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1#argument-mode), e. g. dollar sign followed by variable name causes PS to resolve the variable - as expected. Surprisingly there isn't a rule that covers static variable references, so PowerShell falls back to interpreting the argument as literal string.

Enclosing `[ex1]::count` in parentheses fixes the problem by forcing the parser to leave argument mode and parse an expression.

Full code sample with fix:

```
class ex1 {
    static [int]$count = 0

    ex1() {
        [ex1]::count = [ex1]::count + 1

        # Argument parsing mode -> wrap static variable reference in parentheses
        write-host ([ex1]::count)
    }
}

$ex1 = [ex1]::new()
$ex2 = [ex1]::new()
$ex3 = [ex1]::new()

[ex1]::count  # Expression parsing mode -> no parentheses needed!
```

**Note:** The added last line is an example for PowerShells implicit output feature. By just naming a variable on its own line, PowerShell writes its value to standard output. As there is no command invocation involved, PowerShell is still in *expression parsing* mode, so we don't need to bracketize the expression.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the constructor `ex1() {..}`, you need to add a method that actually returns the value of the static property `Count`:

```
class ex1 {
    [int]static $count = 0

    ex1() {
        # constructor increments the static Count property
        [ex1]::count++
    }
    [int]GetCount() {
        # simply return the current value of Count
        return [ex1]::count
    }
}

$ex1 = [ex1]::new().GetCount()
$ex2 = [ex1]::new().GetCount()
$ex3 = [ex1]::new().GetCount()

$ex1, $ex2, $ex3   # --> resp. 1, 2, 3
```